# Where to find current information on cipher suite strength?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ssh

I am hardening the configuration for my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and have a few choices for `Ciphers`:

```
aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,
aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,
aes256-cbc,arcfour
```

Of these, there are some I know not to use, such as `arcfour`. Beyond that, I often have to search forums and blog posts to find out if a particular cipher suite is still strong. Sometimes this information can be out of date or inaccurate. I have a tough time trusting it.

**Is there a reference or website that keeps up to date information on the relative strength of each cipher suite? Ideally, I'd like to know the current situation for both SSH and TLS settings.** Also, is there any service that will notify you when the list changes (with the addition of a new cipher suite or the degradation of an old one).

Assuming I'm willing and able to upgrade at any point, I'd like to use the strongest and most secure settings available.

Answer (score 4):

Many countries publish Security standards for cipher suited.

In US, you can rely on pci dss standard, fips 140-2, ANSI, EAL, etc.

In France we have the RGS which indicate the algorithms and key length which can be trusted and how many time we can rely on.
I guess every industrialized country has the same standard.

I personally choose to follow this website: https://syslink.pl/cipherlist/
It gathers best Security practices from many sources.

Answer (score 3):

Most vendors using SSL/TLS commonly use OpenSSL who keeps a [detailed record](https://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html) of vulnerabilities associated with SSL/TLS. Subscribing to security sites like [Bugtraq](http://www.securityfocus.com/) will keep you in the loop regarding disclosed (known) vulnerabilities associated with OpenSSL and may tell you about the other [SSL libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Libraries) as well. You would also want to subscribe to other security mailing lists associated with a product. E.g., Microsoft security, Red Hat, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you want information about the estimated strength of the ciphers, I still recommend the [2013 ENISA report](https://www.enisa.europa.eu/publications/algorithms-key-sizes-and-parameters-report/at_download/fullReport). I don't know of any constantly updated list, but the only way the assumptions in that report can change is if some cipher is broken (in the cryptographic sense, not necessary relevant in practice), and that will be widely reported, if it is made public.

If you want to know the best-practices to configure your server(s), I recommend [BetterCrypto.org](https://bettercrypto.org/). They have a draft paper on how to configure the most common software and some explanations. They hopefully will update the draft soon.
Also take a look at [cipherli.st](https://cipherli.st/) like [Sibwara suggested](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/128991/37864).

Answer (score -3):

usually you will consult the NIST website (usa) which is a standard internationnaly.
the FIPS series are here:
https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips

there are also plenty of other standards, one for each agency in the world ...